# How to increase the space between columns in a text file with awk?

Tags: awk

How can I increase the space between columns in a text file with awk?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're trying to make your output more pretty, use [`column`](http://man.cx/column):

```
$ printf "%s %s %s\n" one two three four five six seven eight nine
one two three
four five six
seven eight nine

$ printf "%s %s %s\n" one two three four five six seven eight nine | column -t
one    two    three
four   five   six
seven  eight  nine
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way might be to use a format width specifier. It depends on your data.

```
{ 
    for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++) {
        printf("%9s  ", $i);
    }
    printf("\n") ;
}
```

The `%9` above tells awk to print each field in a space that's 9 characters wide. If the data is wider than 9 characters, awk will use as much space as it needs.

`printf()` is very flexible. For example, for an input file that has four fields, you can do things like this to control the output format.

```
printf("%d   %9s        $d:    %s\n", $1, $2, $3, $4);
```

[Format width in GNU gawk](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Format-Modifiers.html)

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you:

```
cat <<\! >file
> a b c d
> w x y z
> !
cat file
a b c d
w x y z
awk -v OFS='     ' '{$1=$1};1' file
a     b     c     d
w     x     y     z
```